# UITableViewCell frame.size.width is the same for ipad and iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Trying to place a `UILabel` containing the date in the lower right hand corner of a cell whether it's on an iPhone or iPad.

Here's what I currently have, what do I need to do to get the actual cell `size.width`, tried doing `cell.bounds.size.width` as well, same value whether iPhone or iPad:

```
float xValue = cell.frame.size.width - 100;
UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, 20.0f, 100, 17.0f)];
[nameLabel setTag:1];
[nameLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]];
nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
nameLabel.text = @"05-12-13";
// custom views should be added as subviews of the cell's contentView:
[cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
```

ETA, here is the whole custom cell class, maybe someone can see what's causing the duplication of the label:

```
@interface VideoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

+ (VideoTableViewCell *)cellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
+ (CGFloat)heightForVideo:(id<VideoProtocol>)video;
- (void)updateCellForVideo:(id<VideoProtocol>)video;

@end

#define MARGIN 10

@implementation VideoTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        self.textLabel.font  = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

        self.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
        self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (VideoTableViewCell *)cellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSString *identifier = @"TweetCell";
    VideoTableViewCell *cell = (VideoTableViewCell *)[tableView
                                                    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[VideoTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect cvf = self.contentView.frame;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                      0.0,
                                      cvf.size.height-1,
                                      cvf.size.height-1);
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(cvf.size.height + MARGIN,
                              self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,
                              cvf.size.width - cvf.size.height - 2*MARGIN,
                              self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
    self.textLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = CGRectMake(cvf.size.height + MARGIN,
                       self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y,
                       cvf.size.width - cvf.size.height - 2*MARGIN,
                       self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setDateLabelWithDate:(NSDate *)date {


    float xValue = self.frame.size.width - 70;
    // create a custom label:                                        x       y   width  height
    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, 40.0f, 100, 12.0f)];
    dateLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [dateLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];
    dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    dateLabel.text = dateString;
    [self.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
}

+ (CGFloat)heightForVideo:(id<VideoProtocol>)video {

    //create a dummy cell
    VideoTableViewCell *sampleCell  = [[VideoTableViewCell alloc]
                                         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                         reuseIdentifier:nil];
    [sampleCell updateCellForVideo:video];

    //calculate the sizes of the text labels
    CGSize textSize = [video.title sizeWithFont: [VideoTableViewCell textLabelFont]
                                  constrainedToSize:sampleCell.textLabel.frame.size
                                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat minHeight = 51 + 10;  //image height + margin
    return MAX(textSize.height + 20, minHeight);    
}

+ (UIFont *)textLabelFont {
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
}

- (void)updateCellForVideo:(id<VideoProtocol>)video {

    // set the text to the date with the tweet text
    self.textLabel.text = video.title;
    id<VideoAttrProtocol> speaker = [[video.speakers allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.detailTextLabel.text = speaker.name;
    [self setDateLabelWithDate:video.post_date];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:video.thumbnail];    
    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:url
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
}


@end
```

Comment: You need to show the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in your view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the label's autoresizingMask. Put the label in the correct place based on the cell's initial size, whatever it is. With the autoresizingMask set properly, the label will adjust as the cell's size changes.

Just before adding the label to the content view, add:

```
// Keep the label in the bottom-right corner
nameLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Update based on all of the posted code:

In your custom cell, you create and add a label every time the `setDataLabelWithDate:` method is called.

You call this method from `updateCellForVideo:` and possibly from your view controller (you don't show that code).

You need to update your code so you do not add a new label to the cell every time `setDataLabelWithDate:` is called. Only add the label once.

Comment: tried this, it put the label lower then when I started scrolling the cells had labels posted twice inside, some overlapping each other.

Comment: Sounds like you are adding the label over and over. Just add it to a cell once.

Comment: I'm creating that UILabel and adding it to the cell for each cell that's created.  Maybe it's because I'm doing the cell reuse pattern by using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Comment: Only add the label to the cell if the call to `dequeueResuableCell...` returns `nil`.

Comment: @MarkW Please see my updated answer based on your update question.

Comment: Thank's rmaddy, decided to create the UILabel as a private property and only if it is nil to new it up and add it to the cell, otherwise just reset it's text.  Works.